# c++ Constructor initialization with instance of structure

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, instance

Don't know how to put m_Performance into get_Performance

```
struct Performance
{
    double High;
    double Average;
    double Low;
}Perf;
```

Create the structure

```
class Strategy
{ public:
Performance m_Performance(){
    Perf.High = 10.1;
    Perf.Average =5.1;
    Perf.Low =1.1;
};
void get_Performance(){
    m_Performance();     ///This part does not work
}
};
```

Create the class & insert the method, get_Performance. Something's wrong.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Strategy a;
    cout << a.get_Performance << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Wanna get the data member from structure

Comment: I create a structure called Performance & a class called Strategy,Wanna create a instance of structure called m_Performance in the class and a method called get_Performance to return m_Performance.

Comment: A complete minimum working example would help us understand your problem.

Comment: Also, use 'edit' to make your question more clear rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you should:

```
struct Performance
{
    double High;
    double Average;
    double Low;
};

class Strategy
{ 
private:
    Performance m_Performance;
public:
    Strategy() {
        m_Performance.High = 10.1;
        m_Performance.Average = 5.1;
        m_Performance.Low = 1.1;
    }
    Performance get_Performance() {
       return m_Performance;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Strategy a;
    Performance p = a.get_Performance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, figure out to get that.